# skyrimvsmw3.com date format

Tags: discussion

So, I hate to be a nit-picker, but I noticed that http://skyrimvsmw3.com/ uses american-style date formats (mm/dd/yyyy). Seeing as America is the only place in the world that uses this style of formatting, is it possible to get it changed to a universally-readable yyyy.mm.dd format instead?

Even after 25 years of reading dates, I still get initially confused (and thus, a bit frustrated) every time I read a date that doesn't exist (such as 10/31/2011) in my local date format.

I don't know what what the kind of world-wide distribution you get for pageviews, but it's worth a thought?

Comment: Kind of related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101120/use-august-6th-instead-of-8-6-in-maintenance-messages

Comment: http://www.quantcast.com/gaming.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

I generally prefer the [ISO date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for numerical display, 2011-11-13, myself.

Comment: Same. I think that most people understand how to read it as well.

Answer (score 2):

If not the iso date format, at least something like 15/Nov/2011 is quite clear.

Also movies and games say they release in the Fall which I guess is Sept - Nov. Well, Fall, called Autumn in Australia are the months of March - May. So that is confusing to us too. 1st/2nd/3rd/4th quarter if not the actual month name would be nice.

Comment: Yeah, I'm constantly frustrated when I hear that a product is releasing in "the fall", because I never really know *when* that is, and it turns out that "fall" is "spring" for me, but is probably a different season for someone else.